# is it possible to add callback on event dispatching?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

Is it possible somehow to add callback on event in magento without registering observer in for it ?  (like wordpress hooks works)

For example, add callback:

```
    FunctionToAddCallback('catalog_product_save_after', function(){ Mage::log('callback works'); });
```

and after

```
    Mage::dispatchEvent('catalog_product_save_after',array('product'=>$this));
```

It should log 'callback works'.

Is this possible or adding observer is the only way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding an observer is the only way.